# Como ter um intervalo de ciclo, até \n e até \0

Tags: c, condição

Numa função de validação que se passar aos testes todos retornará 1, e se entrar numa das condições irá dar `return` a 0.

Quero fazer um ciclo até a quebra de linha, por isso estou a usar o o intervalo:

```
for(int i=0;dados[4][i]!='\n';i++){
    if(!isdigit(dados[4][i])){
         return 0;
    }
 }
```

O ficheiro já foi divido e guardado numa matriz `dados[4][20]`, sendo as linhas do gênero

```
 4 ; Visitante ; 3 ; 0 ; 3 \n
 4 ; Visitante ; 3 ; 0 ; 3 \n
 4 ; Visitante ; 3 ; 0 ; 3 \0
```

No entanto, na ultima linha do ficheiro, já não existe quebra de linha mas sim um `\0`, logo não nos vai permitir validar a ultima linha

Comment: sugiro que voce coloque mais conteudo para podermos auxiliar. Este for corre um arquivo? ja foi feito o parse das linhas? é um parse dos campos da linha? esse \n é uma quebra de linha? é uma linha vazia? sugiro que edite  e reformule a pergunta.

Comment: vou reformular então

Comment: Mas como foi criado o array ? Porque pela descrição dà a ideia que tem 4 linhas e 20 colunas, mas depois o `for` parece que avança apenas nas colunas ao invés de pelas linhas. Se o array foi criado com um determinado tamanho (20) porque não iterar até 20 ou até à quantidade que foi lida do ficheiro ? Isso seria mais facil e intuitivo. Independentemente de tudo isso "dado o que consegui interpretar da pergunta" parece me que apenas alterar a condição para `dados[4][i]!='\n' && dados[4][i]!='\0'` iria funcionar.

Comment: @BrunoBacelar Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

Assim é bem melhor:

```
for (int i = 0; dados[4][i] != '\n' && dados[4][i] != '\0'; i++) if (!isdigit(dados[4][i])) return 0;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/IsDigits.c).

Comment: Assim não funciona porque se for \n já não é \0....

Comment: assim nao vai funcionar!

Comment: @MichelSimões É, esqueci de trocar o sinal, obrigado. Quem negativou já pode tirar o negativo.

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui resolver o problema adicionando uma condição dentro do for:

```
 for(int i=0;dados[4][i]!='\n';i++){
    if(dados[4][i]=='\0'){
        break;
    }
    if(!isdigit(dados[4][i])){
         return 0;
    }
 }
```